# Close knockout Popover from bootstrap 3.3.6 on click of outside Via knockout binding handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to knockout. I am using knockout and bootstrap 3.3.6(latest). I need to close bootstrap popover on click of out side, via knockout-bootstrap custom binding handlers. I got some plugin for bootstrap 3 custom binding handlers. But I need to close popovers when click of body.

This is my [**sample Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/smzgmmmy/1/)

```
    var guid = (function(s4) {
  return function() {
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
  };
})(function() {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
    .toString(16)
    .substring(1);
});

// Outer HTML
if (!$.fn.outerHtml) {
  $.fn.outerHtml = function () {
    if (this.length === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    var elem = this[0], name = elem.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (elem.outerHTML) {
      return elem.outerHTML;
    }
    var attrs = $.map(elem.attributes, function (i) {
      return i.name + '="' + i.value + '"';
    });
    return "<" + name + (attrs.length > 0 ? " " + attrs.join(" ") : "") + ">" + elem.innerHTML + "</" + name + ">";
  };
}


// Bind Bootstrap Popover
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var popoverBindingValues = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var template = popoverBindingValues.template || false;
    var options = popoverBindingValues.options || {title: 'popover',placement:'bottom'};
    var data = popoverBindingValues.data || false;
    var controlDescendants = popoverBindingValues.controlDescendants;
    if (template !== false) {
      if (data) {
        options.content = "<!-- ko template: { name: template, if: data, data: data } --><!-- /ko -->";
      }
      else {
        options.content = $('#' + template).html();
      }
      options.html = true;
    }
    $element.on('shown.bs.popover', function(event) {

      var popoverData = $(event.target).data();
      var popoverEl = popoverData['bs.popover'].$tip;
      var options = popoverData['bs.popover'].options || {};
      var button = $(event.target);
      var buttonPosition = button.position();
      var buttonDimensions = {
        x: button.outerWidth(),
        y: button.outerHeight()
      };

      ko.cleanNode(popoverEl[0]);
      if (data) {
        ko.applyBindings({template: template, data: data}, popoverEl[0]);
      }
      else {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, popoverEl[0]);
      }

      var popoverDimensions = {
        x: popoverEl.outerWidth(),
        y: popoverEl.outerHeight()
      };

      popoverEl.find('button[data-dismiss="popover"]').click(function() {
        button.popover('hide');
      });

      switch (options.placement) {
        case 'right':
          popoverEl.css({
            left: buttonDimensions.x + buttonPosition.left,
            top: (buttonDimensions.y / 2 + buttonPosition.top) - popoverDimensions.y / 2
          });
          break;
        case 'left':
          popoverEl.css({
            left: buttonPosition.left - popoverDimensions.x,
            top: (buttonDimensions.y / 2 + buttonPosition.top) - popoverDimensions.y / 2
          });
          break;
        case 'top':
          popoverEl.css({
            left: buttonPosition.left + (buttonDimensions.x / 2 - popoverDimensions.x / 2),
            top: buttonPosition.top - popoverDimensions.y
          });
          break;
        case 'bottom':
          popoverEl.css({
            left: buttonPosition.left + (buttonDimensions.x / 2 - popoverDimensions.x / 2),
            top: buttonPosition.top + buttonDimensions.y
          });
          break;
      }
    });

    $element.popover(options);
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
      $element.popover('destroy');
    });

    return { controlsDescendantBindings: typeof controlDescendants == 'undefined' ? true : controlDescendants };

  }
};

var ViewModel = function() {
  this.exampleText = ko.observable(" I am trying to close popover on click of out side using knockout binding handler, Please let me know how to do this");
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

<body>
       <div class="division">
       <button data-bind="popover:{template:'settingsPopover',trigger:'click',placement:'bottom'}">settings</button>
       </div>

        <script type="text/html" id="settingsPopover">
            <div data-bind="text: $data.exampleText" type="text"> </div>


        </script>
        </body>
```

Please suggest best knockout bundling handlers for bootstrap 3.3.6 and help me to close popover on click of out side via knockout handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky thing about this plugin is that it implicitly attaches to the button's click event. It expects the button to be used to toggle the popover's visibility and doesn't give you any way to override that.

A more Knockout way of controlling visibility is (of course) with an observable that would be true when the thing is visible and false otherwise. You might have:

```
this.popoverIsOpen = ko.observable(false);
```

and then in the `update` section of the binding handler something like

```
var openControl = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
$element.popover(openControl ? 'show' : 'hide');
```

What I did for your fiddle was make a controller like that, and put a click binding on the body that always sets it to false:

```
<body data-bind="click: popoverIsOpen.bind($data, false)">
```

And in the `init` section, I set the value to true when it's being shown, and I disabled the button, since I was going to issue my own click event to the button from the body.

```
$element.on('shown.bs.popover', function(event) {
  $element.prop('disabled', true);
  openControl(true);
```

I added a subscription that, if the new value was false, re-enabled the button and closed the popover by triggering a click on the button.

```
openControl.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (!newValue) {
      $element.prop('disabled', false);
      $element.click();
    }
});
```

You can put a click binding on the popover itself to prevent clicks in there from closing:

```
click: function (d,e) {e.stopPropagation();}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smzgmmmy/3/).

Comment: Outside of popover click working fine but, on click of popover body popover shouldn't close. can you update.